# Android Activity onStart called while app is in the background?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-10.0

I've encountered a strange behavior that only seems to be happening on android 10+:

While my activity is in the background, I will open Android Settings, go to System -> Gestures -> System Navigation -> switch between Gesture Navigation & 2-button Navigation.

When I switch these settings, my app (which is running in the background) recreates my activity, and this new activity receives a call to `onStart`, then immediately after `onStop`.

BTW, this behavior is 100% reproducible in this settings flow, but can also occur seemingly at random while the app is in the background.

From my understanding, activities should never be getting a call to `onStart` while they're still in the background, even if they are being destroyed by the OS for whatever reason... or do I have that wrong?

Due to certain functionalities in my app using 3rd party libraries that are called in `onStart`, this behavior causes serious problems when `onStart` is called when the activity is actually in the background.

Has anyone else experienced this? Other than adding delay logic in my `onStart` code (then aborting if followed by an immediate `onStop`), is there anyway to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Hi Gil. Have you specified android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW in the manifest? Also, under: Settings -> Manage Apps -> Your App -> Advanced -> Alert Over Other Apps ON. It is the only Android 10 specific limitation I can think of that makes starting an Activity from the background problematic. Just to add, if this is the problem it should write a special message to logcat stating that the Activity does not have permission to start unless the app is open. Regards

Comment: @Elletlar to clarify, when my activity's onStart is being called, it's not actually coming into the foreground at all. The activity is in the background the entire time, which is why this is so puzzling

Comment: Have you seen this? [Restrictions on starting activities from the background Android 10 - API level 29](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts). In one of my apps, I solved it with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm not actually trying to start my activity. It's been moved to the background, then the OS randomly recreates the activity and calls onStart, followed by a quick onStop. The app does not move to the foreground when this happens. AFAIK, onStart shouldn't be getting called here.. it seems to be an OS glitch.

Comment: Just to be clear, does it call onCreate before onStart?

Comment: Yes it does, and then onStop immediately after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onStart()` will be called on apps in the background. There isn't anything that says that Android will not do this. The only thing you can really rely on is `onResume()` and `onPause()`. `onResume()` is called when the `Activity` is in the foreground and has the user's focus. `onPause()` is called when the `Activity` had the user's focus and Android is giving the user's focus to another `Activity`.

It looks like, in your case, Android is causing a configuration change to be propagated to all apps, which may be why you see the background apps being "woken up" like this, but this is just a guess from me.

Comment: Thanks for this, makes sense!